# "An error occurred. Detailed message: 1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge"

Tags: git, visual-studio

I tried to merge the branch `feature1` into `master` using **Visual Studio 2015** and I received this error:

[image]

There's no changes in current branch:

[image]

[image]

But, when I tried to merge using following commands, it worked:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature1
```

How can I resolve this issue in Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in Visual Studio's Git plugin.  It would not be the first time such a thing has happened.